# QVariant holding QSet<QString> comparison does not work as expected, while the bare QSet<QString> works fine

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QSet<QString>` which I store in `QVariant` and then I try to compare it with an identical object. While `QSet<QString>` comparison works, this is no longer the case when they are wrapped within `QVariant`. Any ideas or workarounds? I need to compare the `QVariant` in unit tests with `QCOMPARE()`:

```cpp
    QSet<QString> s1({"str"});
    QSet<QString> s2({"str"});

    QVariant v1;
    QVariant v2;

    v1.setValue(s1);
    v2.setValue(s2);

    qDebug() << QString::number(v1 == v2); // 0
    qDebug() << QString::number(s1 == s2); // 1
    qDebug() << QString::number(s1.value<QSet<QString>>() == s2.value<QSet<QString>>()); // 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be made to work but it turns out there's a bit of manual labour to be done.  From the [`QVariant::operator==` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#operator-eq-eq)...

> **Warning**: To make this function work with a custom type registered with
>   qRegisterMetaType(), its comparison operator must be registered using
>   QMetaType::registerComparators()

Even though `qRegisterMetaType()` hasn't been used in this case it appears that `QMetaType::registerComparators()` still needs to be called.  The [`documentation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#registerComparators) for that states further that for a type `T`, a successful call to `QMetaType::registerComparators<T>()` `"...requires T to have both an operator== and an operator<"`.  In this case `QSet` already has an equality operator but no `operator<` so that needs to be implemented.  Putting the bits together gives...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QSet>
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>

template<typename T>
bool operator< (const QSet<T> &a, const QSet<T> &b)
{
  auto ia = a.begin();
  auto ib = b.begin();
  while (true) {
    if (ia == a.end() || ib == b.end())
      return a.size() < b.size();
    if (*ia < *ib)
      return true;
    ++ia;
    ++ib;
  }
  return false;
}

int main ()
{
  QMetaType::registerComparators<QSet<QString>>();
  QSet<QString> s1({"str"});
  QSet<QString> s2({"str"});

  QVariant v1;
  QVariant v2;

  v1.setValue(s1);
  v2.setValue(s2);

  std::cout << (v1 == v2) << "\n";
  std::cout << (s1 == s2) << "\n";
  std::cout << (v1.value<QSet<QString>>() == v2.value<QSet<QString>>()) << "\n";
}
```

Basic testing gives the output...

```
1
1
1
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, works like charm! Nevertheless, I am wondering why Qt does not support such behavior by default. Also not supporting `QSet<T>` in the constructor of `QVariant` is annoying. Anyway, I have your workaround, thank you again!